# SP2010: Is modifying of admin content DB stored procedure permissionssions allowed?

Tags: 2010, database

I'm having a problem in production environment with help pages. Basically the problem is that the application pool account for some reason does not have permissions to run the required stored procedure in admin content DB. The actual error and fix is described here -> http://sharepointrelated.com/2011/10/05/sharepoint-2010-help-content-cannot-be-displayed/

It would be really easy just to add that permissions, but we must naturally follow the supported database actions listed by MS (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057). In that page it states that changing the stored procedures is unsupported action.

Is there any other workaround for this or are permission changes allowed in sharepoint databases? We would not basically change the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You'll not be modifying the Stored Procedure only the permissions on it.

And it'll be easy to restore the original permissions.

Comment: On several occasions you will find yourself assigning permissions directly to content databases, so should be fully supported